# SonarQube Custom Java rule for class inside annotation

Tags: java, annotations, sonarqube

I want to execute an analysis in a class **only if** that class is inside an annotation of another class.
This example will explain it better:

Here is my class:

```
package sonar.special;

public class MySpecialClass {

    private String specialField;

    public void methodSpecial() {

    }
}
```

And want to check something like if it has a method call `methodSpecial()` or if it has a field call `specialField`, it could be anything, these are just examples.

But I need to make those checks **only if** the class is inside an annotation of another class.
For example we have defined this annotation there the value is a list of classes:

```
package sonar.annotations;

public @interface SpecialClasses {

    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

And here is my first class inside the annotation:

```
package sonar.configuration;

import sonar.annotations.SpecialClasses;
import sonar.special.MySpecialClass;

@SpecialClasses({
        MySpecialClass.class
})
public class Configuration {
}
```

There may be a lot of classes like `Configuration` spread all over the code.

My question is:
standing in the analysis of MySpecialClass, is there any way to see if it is contained in the value of an annotation of another class?

Maybe we can go the other way, and from the analysis of the class `Configuration` we can get to the other class (`MySpecialClass`) and make the analysis. But in that case I need the issue to be shown in the UI in the MySpecialClass, and I don't know if that is possible as I only have the ClassTree of Configuration.

Comment: Why don't you go the other way? Not sure if you can ask Sonar to analyze these classes, but I'm pretty sure we can ask sonar to ignore few classes inside few packages.

Comment: scan all classes and then use IssueFilter https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/scan/issue/filter/IssueFilter.java